# SELECT returns empty resultset

Tags: postgresql

When I try to insert and select data from a table, I get an empty result set. I do it like this:

```
reestr-# INSERT INTO datatype(code) VALUES ('blabla')
reestr-# SELECT * FROM datatype
reestr-#
```

So, I get no errors or warnings in the console, but still I'm unable to insert or select any data. By the way, I even tried to insert into an invalid field `cod` instead of `code` and got no errors - this is really strange.

Comment: PostgreSQL is waiting for you to finish your command with a `;`. Whatever you enter is not evaluated or executed until you do so.

Comment: Oh, that is absolutely right. Thank you, sir!

Comment: @Patrick: It's the client psql that's waiting, not the PostgreSQL database server. You could also change this default behavior using the --single-line setting in psql

Comment: Also, take a look at the prompt, it was "=#", then it goes to "-#", the "-" means it is waiting for ";" to finish the command. Of course if you do that now you'll see an error, as both commands will be joined, so press Ctrl+C and start again... :)

Answer (score 24):

end your query with a `;` => `SELECT * FROM datatype;`